# How to create a circle drawable?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

How to a create a `drawable` of a circle, with blue stroke of 5 pixels and a transparent fill.

I will be passing this `drawable` to an `ItemizedOverlay` .

I want to do this with code and I will know the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       type="OvalShape" >
   <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#99104E8B"/>
   ....
</shape>
```

Just put something like this in an XML file in you drawables directory and load it as you would a normal image.

See ShapeDrawable in the Android Docs.

Comment: This seems like the best idea, then I can just change the bounds at run time I guess.

Comment: Yes you can.  You load it in your app the same way you'd load an image. You can set the bounds via the setBound() method.  See the docs.

Comment: there seems to be a type in the above answer: it should be `android:type="oval"` rather than `type=OvalShape"`

Comment: Everything about this answer is incorrect, it should be removed.