# How to create a shape in android on which we can write text

Tags: android

Basically I want to be able to write text on a sort of sticky note/shapes like we do in powerpoint (something like:http://www.indezine.com/images/blog/circletext01.gif), but in android. I am an absolute beginner in android. How do I do this?
I am using android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom view, a class that extends the View class.

Then override the **onDraw(Canvas canvas)** method. use the **canvas.drawText** and **canvas.drawBitmap** to draw your shape and text.

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable that is circular in shape and set it as the background of the textView or editText that you are using. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6052178/2683275) in order to create a circular drawable.